# What is the general approach for private and public fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

What is the general approach for defining security rules for certain fields for a path.

For example, a user has a the following data:

```
{
    name: "John Doe",
    organization: "John Doe Inc",
    salary: "$1"
}
```

How would I define a security rule to indicate that the public can only read `name` and `organization` but only John Doe is able to see his own `salary` field?

Is better to create a `/public/` and a `/private/` path for each user to explicitly define the `public` and `private` properties?

like so:

```
{
    public: {
        name: "John Doe",
        organization: "John Doe Inc."
    },
    private: {
        salary: "$1"
    }
}
```

What is a good approach for this?

Comment: Given that Firebase's security works top-down (once you have access, it cannot be removed at a lower level), your first example is almost impossible to secure. https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade  I would probably split public/private at a top-level, so with a public AddressBook and private Users nodes.

Comment: ok, I see. So in the case of adding an address to the address book, an authenticated user would need to `push()` data to two places? The public data at the `/public/` location and the private data in the `/private/` location? (Then of course, linking those two locations with and index? :/ )

Comment: Yup, that's what I would consider. You *can* probably get things working by securing fields at a lower level. But I often prefer the simplicity that data-duplication brings in a case like this. Of course YMMV.

Comment: What about segmenting the data in public/private collections on a per entity basis. So I would have `addressBook/public` and `addressBook/private`. Each of those fields would then have their own security rules. From what I understand, if there are no security rules defined for a path, firebase defaults to `false` -- so the public would be able to access `adressBook/public`, but not `adressbook/`. Would that work?